# How to convert existing html popups to modal popups using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

My legacy UI application has HTML popups that I'd like to convert to Modal popups in Javascript.  Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try jqueyr UI dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: I think you need to supply more information to what you really mean. Are you looking for a library that supply UI behaviors and widgets? You're looking for an explanation on how you might tackle such a feat? Do you search for a stable way to implement the change without compromising current behavior? The more details you give, the easier it will be to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IFRAME with something like jquery's modal dialog.  I usually find JavaScript modal popups are not entirely modal.  E.g. they rely on CSS to position a container over the top of the screen to capture all non-dialog events, but keyboard access is usually still possible.  This one is pretty robust though: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Using an IFRAME would be the easiest transition from real popups to pseudo JS popups as the documents served within the popup would require little modification if any.